# Triac moc3041 resistors

Tags: opto-isolator, triac

I'm trying to understand few things about triacs etc. and I found datasheet for MOC3041

[image]

And there're two resistors which purpose I don't really understand. I'm talking about the 330Ohm and 360Ohm resistors. What they're used to? Is it for some gate protection? And if so, why, when I'm seeing other schematics (not from DS), there's never that gate-load resistor?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 360 ohm resistor limits the current if the optotriac gets turned on at relatively high voltage. This could happen as a result of a transient (voltage or dv/dt)- the internal zero cross should normally inhibit it except near the zero crossing.

The 330 ohm resistor prevents a sensitive gate triac from turning on if the leakage from the optotriac is high (which might typically happen at high temperatures). It may not be needed if the triac is relatively insensitive.